# set username and password in EmbeddedCassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, embedded-cassandra

I´m trying to use `EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper` but setting a specific username and password to connect.

I´m trying to find in the documentation and reading the API but I can only see that is possible pass a `yaml` file with the `startEmbeddedCassandra` but no idea the structure of that yaml file and if it is possible to set a username and password.

Any idea how to do it?

Regards

Comment: what do you want to achieve? YAML file that EmbeddedCassandra accepts is just standard cassandra.yaml - configure local Cassandra instance to work with authentication, and then use the same file for EmbeddedCassandra (although you may need to adjust ports, not to clash with locally installed Cassandra)

Comment: Is what I´m trying to do now. I get a cassandra.yaml standard template and I just change AllowAllAuthenticator by PasswordAuthenticator. But now I'm trying to figure how to pass the file to the EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper, the API accept a String as yaml file (I guess the path) or just the file. I'm trying both

Comment: IIRC, it should be a path, but I could be wrong